# Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\not=0,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ divergence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n\not=0,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ divergence.

Comment: $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$ where $s_n$ is the $n-$th partial sum.

Comment: Use the Cauchy criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is better if you prove the contrapositive of that statement. Using your hint $s_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$, then $a_{n+1}=s_{n+1}-s_{n}$ for every $n\geq1$, since $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}$ converges we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=\ell$ for some $\ell\in\mathbb{R}$, therefore:
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(s_{n+1}-s_{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n+1}-\lim_{n\to\infty}s_{n}=\ell-\ell=0.
\end{equation*}